# Is it possible to cancel a graphql query inside config.options?

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Let's say I have this portion of code:

```js
export default graphql(MyQuery, {
  options: (props) => ({
    variables: {
      var1: props.var1,
      var2: props.var2,
      var3: props.var3
      /* I want to do this: 
         if (props.var4 == "Donot query") /* Cancel this query; */
      */
    }
  })
})(DumbComponent)
```

Is it possible to do this?
Reason is my props is injected by Redux store. Some of the query needs a combination of changes to var1 & var2 for example to fetch the correct data. However, sometimes some action will change only var1 in Redux, and that will trigger the graphql query and yield incorrect data. For those cases, I want to cancel the query.

I know this problem can be solved by design. Meaning we can create a set of variables required for the query separately in Redux, and any action touches this set, need to touch individual in the set.

However, doing so will require Redux to be aware of specific graphql query, creating a tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "cancel the query", you might be able to use the `skip` option:

```
export default graphql(MyQuery, {
  skip: (props) => !! props.var4,
  options: (props) => ({
    variables: {
      var1: props.var1,
      var2: props.var2,
      var3: props.var3
    }
  })
})(DumbComponent)
```

See the docs for that here: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-graphql.html#graphql-config-skip

Comment: I did try skip, it is not designed for this purpose. It will skip the entire query, and 'remove' my inject data from props. I want to be able to retain old injected data in props, otherwise the component won't render.

Comment: One thing you could do is copy the data into state, or simply not set the variables until they are ready

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63891561/1848109)

I have made a POC that shed's light on  - *how to cancel Apollo GraphQL pending request*. Modify the source code to fit your requirement.

*Happy Coding!*