# stop pending requests with apollo client hooks

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

It looks like its [possible](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/40#issuecomment-554561836) to cancel pending requests via `client.stop()` but the documentation is not showing us a solution when we use `apollo client hooks` where we have no `client`.

How to stop pending requests using apollo client hooks ?

Answer (score 5):

**Struggled for days and made a proof of concept that finally works.**

I have explained the code below and here is my POC - [Github source code](https://github.com/nirus/fullstack-tutorial).

---

**Explaination:**

**Step – 1:**
Create a middleware that holds the logic to track and cancel duplicate request via ReactJS context API – [`cancelRequest.tsx`](https://github.com/nirus/fullstack-tutorial/blob/master/final/client/src/cancelRequest.ts) (complete source code)

**Step – 2:**
Generate namespace UUID and pass it using **requestTrackerId** via query context as below.

```
context:{ 
  requestTrackerId: uuidNameSpace('LOGIN', RequestNameSpace) 
}
```

*Refer source code -* [Line 32](https://github.com/nirus/fullstack-tutorial/blob/cc50338b9577d58bf1e19c5b32368dfd236405f2/final/client/src/pages/login.tsx#L32)

**Step – 3:**
Finally, wiring all the middleware and setup it up as funnel layers using `from` API of Apollo GraphQL client and set [queryDeduplication](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/networking/network-layer/#query-deduplication) to `false`.

---

### Mechanism of action:

When ever more than one request originates from the same mutation query, each query is tagged to its `requestTrackerId` which remains same to that particular query and different for other queries.

Using [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library namespace is generated for each query (Read the code). With this ID the middleware associates each query to its namespace generated ID and stores in a cache object.

Subsequent incoming request are looked up using the cache object. If there’s an ongoing request which is not yet completed, it will be aborted immediately using [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) javascript API and this request is replaced with new request.

### Libraries used

- [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) – Used to create unique request tracker ID and prevent namespace
  collision for multiple request from same component.
- ReactJS – No intro needed i guess?
- Apollo GraphQL – Follow the link to know more..

*Hope this answer helps. Happy coding*

Comment: Please explain the basis for your solution here

Comment: @mohas its explained in the blog post motivation and steps.

Comment: I ended up leaving the request alone and just ignore the redux or component update if the component was unmounted

Comment: @mohas are you using **redux-saga**? Also post a your source github or fiddler  link so that i can take look at it.

Comment: yes the problem arises when response from mutation tries to update redux saga when the component is unmounted so I tried to skip store updates when the component is unmounted

Comment: Sorry, but your answer not clear. Please explain here

Comment: It would be great to have at least a short explanation here. Also, the blog link is not secure right this moment.

Comment: @Dabrule - Updated here.